# Sequelize cli model creation

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I've been trying to create a `user model` using sequelize cli but whenever I insert more parameters like primary key and unique the parser fails. Eg:

```
npx sequelize model:create --name user --attributes "name:{dataType:string, primaryKey:true}, email:string, address:string" --force

Sequelize CLI [Node: 8.10.0, CLI: 5.4.0, ORM: 5.1.0]


ERROR: Attribute 'name:{dataType:string, primaryKey:true}' cannot be parsed: Cannot read property 'dataType' of undefined
```

I haven't found any reference in the [Docs](https://github.com/sequelize/cli/tree/master/docs) about this. Is there any way to  do it?

Comment: did you found the right way to do it please ?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I switched to another solution instead

Answer (score 0):

You can find the available list of commands here

https://github.com/sequelize/cli