# Use sequelize-cli to specify multiple constraints in the model:generate command

Tags: node.js, orm, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

Following the [documentation](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/migrations.html) to generate model and migration at the same time, we can use:
*npx sequelize-cli model:generate --name User --attributes firstName:string,lastName:string,email:string*

This generates a model file.js with:

```
    User.init({
        firstName: DataTypes.STRING,
        lastName: DataTypes.STRING,
        email: DataTypes.STRING
    }
```

But I want to specify additional condition/properties, like:

```
User.init({
    user_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,   <====
        primaryKey: true,   <====
      },
    firstName: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false   <====
    },
    lastName: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING
    }
  }
```

Is there a way for me to specify additional params than just the datatype... like primaryKey, autoIncrement, or allowNull?

There is already a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55250474/sequelize-cli-model-creation), but no working answer.

Thanks in advance